# Windows update on netbook requires CD (hint, there's no CD drive)

Tags: windows, netbook, updates

An "Important" update for Microsoft Works (via Windows Update) on a Dell netbook gets about halfway through and then pops up with the super-awesome "Please insert Microsoft Works 9.0 disc" message.  Of course, the netbook has no CD rom drive, there is no handy folder (that i can find) containing "Works9.msi", and I have no Works9 disc.  It wouldn't be so bad, except the update keeps coming up everytime WU runs.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Wowwwwwwww, they still make Works?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option here (really) is to uninstall Microsoft Works.  At this point Windows will stop complaining about the missing update.  If you don't have another office suite and don't want to pay for full MS Office, you can download Open Office or use http://office.live.com instead.

Comment: uninstall it is, and good call on office live

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a netbook with come with reinstallation CDs even though there's no CD-ROM drive.  If that's the case, you could copy those files onto a thumb-drive from another computer.

If not, you may have to contact Dell and request that they send the CD to you.

If you don't even use Microsoft Works, you can just uninstall it or tell Windows update not to install any updates for Works.

Comment: Even if you don't use Works you need to keep it patched (just because you don't use it doesn't mean an exploit won't). Either keep it patched or un-install.